# Android SDK Manager fails to open in eclipse on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, eclipse

I've installed "eclipse-java-2018-09-linux-gtk-x86_64" on ubuntu 18.04 and add ADT to eclipse for android development.

When I open eclipse an error message is shown about getting the required ADT version number from SDK and suggesting to fix it using SDK Manager, But when I try to open the SDK Manager it won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of android SDK won't work with eclipse because eclipse's support has been removed. but it is still possible to create android app using eclipse by using the older version of SDK. try to download android SDK tools 22. Extract it in your home folder, set it in eclipse Windows-preferences-android-sdk_path. do not update any sdk components higher than 22. here is my screen shot of android sdk manager that works fine on ubuntu 16.04 32-bit system with eclipse kepler. [image]if you want to use latest version of SDK then you have to use android-studio.